# Is there a place to store bags in Gokurakabashi railway station or Mount Koya?

Tags: japan, luggage-storage

I have a backpack and a suitcase that fits roughly in an airplane's overhead compartment. My plan is to travel from Osaka to Mt. Koya, then from there to Kyoto, and during the day I'd rather not need to shuffle around with my luggage.

Is there a place in Gokurakabashi or Mt. Koya where I can store my bags for the day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Nankai railway's homepage](http://www.nankai.co.jp/traffic/station/koyasan) and to [another guide](http://www.howto-osaka.com.e.iv.hp.transer.com/top/railway/station/koyasan/) there are lockers in Koyasan station but not in Gokurakubashi.

Anyway, if I remember correctly, you have to take the Nankai line from Osaka Namba station to Gokurakubashi and again you will have to change at the same station on your way back to Kyoto so, probably, you are more likely to find a locker at the Namba station on a busy day.